# What can the Indian government do to help Indian students in Ukraine amid the war situation?

Tags: russian-federation, law, ukraine, international-law, india

Indian students in Ukraine (mostly studying medicine) have been recently advised to return to India shortly after many of them went back to their Ukrainian universities. Many students had been complaining that the Indian government knows that it's not affordable and practicable for the students to keep flying to and from. They just want to finish their graduation and get into practice.

Indian laws don't allow them to directly transfer to medical colleges in India, nor can they stay in their home country; the only option, they say, is to take refuge in [Slovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovakia) and other neighbouring countries.

I want to understand why the Indian government isn't doing something about it, or what it could actually do to protect them or fix this and/or similar situations that might arise in the future for their students flying abroad for studies.

Comment: Could you clarify on why it's not affordable to fly back to India? If you don't have money to come back to your country, how the war is changing that situation? And normally, if you don't have money to come back, you won't be allowed to go abroad in the first line.

Comment: You make a valid point in a general context. What I inferred from the news was, the war situation led the students to fly back and forth relatively more than usual in this particular time period, partly because of the wavering advisories by the Indian Govt influenced by the changing war conditions, hence unaffordable. (Usually-- once students travel to their country of study, they return to India maybe once or rarely a few times a year)

Comment: I’m extremely confused as to why the Indian government should help those who voluntarily returned to Ukraine after the war has started.

Comment: Fair point! I think, the news focused on or the respondents were majorly the students who're in their final or pre-final year (as was mentioned as well), worried about finishing their degree more than safety?!

Answer (score 15):

Generally, when one's citizens find themselves in a war, there is a duty to assist one's citizens to safety. The extent of assistance given is to "get out of the war-torn country".  That is the Government of India would be expected to do what it can to enable Indians who were in Ukraine in Feb 2022 assistance to leave the country safely.

Once they are back home and safe, there is no specific duty or responsibility to, for example, require that local schools in India accept them.

People have been advised to avoid Ukraine since then.  It is currently being invaded by a foreign power, and so it isn't a suitable place to go to study.  If someone ignores that advice their access to consular assistance is reduced. If someone doesn't want to leave Ukraine, there is little the government can or should do.

The issue here is that a group of students choose to return to Ukraine to continue studies in August because they were unable to find a medical degree place in India, and are *refusing* to return to India, unless they are able to continue their studies remotely.

One thing that the government could do is to recognise the validity of online courses.  However medicine is very much a practical subject, and there is much that can't be learnt by "zoom".

Answer (score 6):

In a situation like that, a government might:

- Organize a [non-combatant evacuation operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-combatant_evacuation_operation) from the conflict area.
  That means armed forces enter the conflict zone, either with the permission of the conflict parties or with the threat of firing at any side which interferes with their evacuation. India appears unwilling to take that step.
- Organize an evacuation operation of displaced nationals from nearby safe locations.
  India actually did that, [it seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Ganga). The operation was somewhat complicated by visa issues. The EU countries only belatedly extended the refugee programs for Ukrainian *citizens* to other *residents* of Ukraine. As of now, it is possible to enter the EU and then travel onwards towards India. It may or may not be possible to stay in the EU, depending on the residence status in Ukraine *before* the start of the Russian attack.

Answer (score 2):

They could work on unifying and standardizing the education programs with EU.

It is very strange for me to read that Indian laws do not allow to finish studies in Indian medical colleges, at least assuming that medical education obtained in Ukraine would otherwise be recognised.  If really so, it should probably be checked if this is reasonable. [Student exchange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_exchange_program) is not something unheard of.

Comment: The transfer of credit points or partial degree requirements from one educational system ot another can be difficult.

Comment: Student exchanges are popular since WWII and longest of them last up to one year that may be enough to finish the education. Somehow they have these problems resolved.

Comment: Admission to India's medical colleges is extremely competitive, with about 2 million applicants and about 100,000 seats. Most of the students that study abroad are allegedly those that cannot compete in this system. 
The school of thought is that would be unfair to offer these students seats in India's medical colleges.